# SQL Cursor and Email

Tags: sql, email, database-cursor

I have a cursor in place that needs to send an email to one person containing all the rows associated with a certain field

To explain a bit further, i have a table which contains multiple rows, with one field containing the email address for all the rows associated with that email address.

I'm looking to send one email for that user with all the rows associated with that email address. At the moment, so if it has 4 rows, sends one email with all those rows. What its doing at the moment is sending 4 emails with all the rows associated with that email address

Essentially, just need it to send one email with all the rows for that email address

Thanks

Cursor loops through
Updates a table
Email then uses the variables to send the email

```
DECLARE @SUBJECT VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @BODY VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @EMAIL VARCHAR(60)
DECLARE @SUPERVISOREMAIL VARCHAR(60)
DECLARE @TABLEHTML VARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @TPROFILE VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @ASSETREF VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @PERSONREF VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @USERNAME VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @UPDATEDINVFIRE BIT
DECLARE @DATEUPDATEDINVFIRE DATETIME
DECLARE @DEVICEMODEL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE CSR CURSOR
FOR SELECT ASSETREF, USERNAME, EMAIL, SUPERVISOREMAIL, UPDATEDINVFIRE, DATEUPDATEDINVFIRE  FROM ##LEAVERUPDATE

OPEN CSR FETCH NEXT
    FROM CSR INTO @ASSETREF, @USERNAME, @EMAIL, @SUPERVISOREMAIL, @UPDATEDINVFIRE, @DATEUPDATEDINVFIRE
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

SET @SUBJECT = 'VFIRE DEVICE STATUS UPDATED FOR LEAVER'
SET @TABLEHTML = N'<P> The following user has had the following devices set to leaver status in vFire</P>' +
            N'<P> Please be advised, these devices need to be returned immediately prior to the person leaving the business</P>' +
            N'<table border="1">' +
            N'<tr><th>CI Number</th><th>Username</th><th>Asset Model</th><th>Asset Description</th><th>Users Email Address</th><th>Supervisor EMail Address</th></tr>' +
            CAST
                ((
                    SELECT 
                    TD = ASSETREF, '',
                    TD = USERNAME, '',
                    TD = DEVICEMODEL, '',
                    TD = DESCRIPTION,'',
                    TD = EMAIL, '',
                    TD = SUPERVISOREMAIL,''
                    FROM ##LEAVERUPDATE
                        WHERE EMAIL = @EMAIL
                        FOR XML PATH('TR'), TYPE
                        ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +
                            N'</TABLE>' +
                                N'<P> </P>'; 

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
        @profile_name = @TPROFILE,
        @recipients = @SUPERVISOREMAIL,
        @copy_recipients='',
        @blind_copy_recipients ='',
        @subject = @SUBJECT,
        @body = @TABLEHTML,
        @body_format = 'HTML'
------------------------------------------
FETCH NEXT
    FROM CSR INTO @ASSETREF, @USERNAME, @EMAIL, @SUPERVISOREMAIL, @UPDATEDINVFIRE, @DATEUPDATEDINVFIRE

END

CLOSE CSR
DEALLOCATE CSR
```

Comment: please share your code to us. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @jose_bacoy code added above. Apologies if it doesnt look the best

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is very product specific.)

Comment: Sorry, using SQL Server 2014